# HTML-Form validation

Tags: javascript, html

Using an internal JavaScript as follows:

```
<script>
function validateForm()
{
    var x=document.forms["myForm"]["firstName"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
    {
        document.getElementById('usernameError').innerHTML = "Invalid First Name";
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

How will I insert error text for the user in place of the comment here:

```
<form name="myForm" action="someAction" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()" >
<fieldset class='step'>
    <legend id="usernameError">Personal Information</legend>
    <p>
        <label for='firstName'>First Name:</label>
        <input type='text' name='firstName' id='firstName' />
        <!--Is JavaScript able to insert/append text here?-->
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Have an interal javascript insert text in an html

Comment: In general, validate a form

Comment: try required at the end of input no need to any other validation that will generate automaticaly validation for eg <input type=text required />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert or append will cause to multiple error-messages that will keep if the user correct the field.

Overwrite is what you shall do.

Try this:

```
<p>
    <label>First Name:
        <input type="text" name="firstName" />
    </label>
    <div id="usernameError"><!-- empty at start --></div>
</p>
```

Comment: BTW: You dont need a attribute `for` if you can enclose the `input`.

Comment: With the same javascript? I get nothing after submitting. I would expect to see the error message from the javascript.

Comment: Is the id `usernameError` unique in the HTML-Document and do you have any javascript-messages?